# One or two mics to cover most budget studio applications?

Tags: recording, microphones

I don't currently own any microphones. I recently ordered a computer audio interface with phantom power and instrument level inputs. I'm interested in recording voice, traditional instruments, and found objects in a studio setting. I will not be performing live. I'm on a very tight budget ($150).

What type of microphone(s) would best fit my requirements? I figure that I need a good condenser mic for vocals, correct? Should I purchase two specialized microphones, one for vocals and one for drums/bass? This is my current thinking:

Vocals & High-Pitched Sounds
https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=600800

Drums, Bass, etc.
[https://www.amazon.com/Nady-DM-90-Dynamic-Kick-Microphone/dp/B0002E516M/ref=sr_1_4?s=musical-instruments&ie=UTF8&qid=1488312827&sr=1-4&keywords=nady+drum+mic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002E516M)

If possible, please suggest a single type of mic or an appropriate pair of mic types and explain your reasoning. If you know of a particular model of that type, I would appreciate the example.

Thank you,
-d. vyd

Comment: I'd say drop the Nady drum mic and instead go with a multipurpose instrument microphone such as the [Shure SM57](https://www.amazon.com/Shure-SM57-LC-Cardioid-Dynamic-Microphone/dp/B0000AQRST/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1488321550&sr=8-1&keywords=SM57).  It's a little pricey, but the extra cost is worth it in my opinion.

Comment: Just get one good mic. You don't need two different ones.

Comment: The monoprice certainly seems like a good buy, with shockmount, but no cable. If you envisage stereo recordings, you're going to need two of whatever, and matched mics make more sense then.

Comment: It takes 4 mics to really do justice to a drum set.  One for each singer, then special arrangements for each instrument.  But if you are simply adding vocals to a back track, then one mic is all you need.  The time-tested Shure SM58 is just fine.  Inexpensive, nearly indestructible, and they sound good.